# Optix rendering appears to actually be doing CUDA instead of Optix

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Optix rendering appears to actually be doing CUDA instead of Optix.  I selected Optix, but it takes the same amount of time to render as when I select CUDA. I have updated my Nvidia driver to version 456.38 Studio Driver for my RTX 2080 Video card.  Perhaps Blender needs to update their render kernels to work with newer Nvidia drivers?  A couple of versions ago of Nvidia drivers, Optix did work.

Comment: Maybe is not related but I read somewhere that there is a bug in the latest Nvidia drivers and the new RTX

Comment: Same here but with docker on amazon with t4 gpu